# Using Image (Pillow)/Pytesseract (Python): FineNotFound: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: python

On a little project I had an issue with on of the two modules, so I created a short code to see where the problem comes from.

Here is my code:

```
import pytesseract
from PIL import Image

text= pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open('pict.jpg'))
```

With this, I get the same error:

> FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2]The system cannot find the file specified

and PyScripter open the subprocess.py file and show me the following line:

```
# Start the process
            try:
                hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args,
                                         # no special security
                                         None, None,
                                         int(not close_fds),
                                         creationflags,
                                         env,
                                         cwd,
                                         startupinfo)
```

When I googled this issue, it looked like my version of pytesseract was causing this. I tried to install different versions of pytesseract or Pillow, but the error still occurs.

What should I do ? How can I be sure that my installation is proper ?

Thanks.

**EDIT1:** 
I tried adding this to make sure the module directory is in the system path:

```
sys.path.insert(0,'C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages\pytesseract')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like `pytesseract` can't find your installation of Tesseract. Ensure that the folder containing `tesseract.exe` [is in your system path](https://superuser.com/questions/284342/what-are-path-and-other-environment-variables-and-how-can-i-set-or-use-them) so that the module can actually run the binary.

If you don't want to modify your environment variables, you can manually specify the full path:

```
import pytesseract

pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r'C:\Path\To\tesseract.exe'
                          # ^ the `r` is needed to have the backslashes
                          # be interpreted as literal backslashes

# The rest of your code
```

Comment: Well I don't have a tesseract.exe file, but a pytesseract.py. I tried with this, and it still doesn't work.

Comment: I added a line to put it in system path. See edit in first post

Comment: @ColChope: [`pytesseract`](https://github.com/madmaze/pytesseract/blob/master/src/pytesseract.py) is a 275 line script that just interfaces with `tesseract.exe`, it doesn't do anything on its own. You still need to actually install Tesseract.

Comment: I used pip to install it. I'll search for a valid pack.

Comment: @ColChope: `pip` installs Python packages, you'll need to download and install tesseract for Windows separately: https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/wiki

Comment: Well now I have the .exe file and when I run "import pytesseract", everything looks fine, I have no error message... But if I try the code, same error

Comment: @ColChope: Did you add the folder containing `tesseract.exe` to your system PATH or directly point to the binary?

Comment: Isn't it what I tried with the line I added to my question ? (in the Edit)

Comment: Alright it works, I had to install from pip and from github and then use both of your code and the code I put in the edit. Apparently, "import pytesseract" doesn't work so I used "from pytesseract import pytesseract".  Thanks a lot!